# AmpScript - Show salutations if name field more than 3 character, omit salutation if 2 or less

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

Our data seems mostly correct, but there are some names that are either blank or are 2 random letters. We would like our email to start with "Dear _Salutation" but want that field to hide if the name is less than 3 characters, or is blank altogether. Appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 1):

I would have have a look at [IIF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/iif.htm) in Ampscript, if I were you.  E.g:

```
%%=IIF((length(@name)>2),@salutation,’’)=%%
```